# Cancel an iOS scheduled LocalNotification using id (Titanium)

Tags: javascript, ios, notifications, titanium, uilocalnotification

I'm using Titanium SDK 3.1. I want to cancel a scheduled LocalNotification (iOS). I saw that method `Ti.App.iOS.cancelLocalNotification(Number id)` (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS) but I don't know how to specify the `id` when I create a `Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification(<NotificationParams>)`. I read that I have to create a property called `id`inside the `userInfo` property but I couldn't get it to work.

Example code (doesn't work):

```
Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody : "My notification",
    badge : 0,
    repeat : "daily",
    userInfo : {
         id : 1234
    },
    sound : "alarm.mp3",
    date : new Date()
});

Ti.App.iOS.cancelLocalNotification(1234); // => undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the code as follows

```
Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody : "My notification",
    badge : 0,
    repeat : "daily",
    userInfo : {
         "id" : 1234
    },
    sound : "alarm.mp3",
    date : new Date()
});

Ti.App.iOS.cancelLocalNotification(1234);
```

I have updated the object `userInfo` in your code since [userInfo](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/NotificationParams-property-userInfo) is a dictionary type.

> From [Appcelerator docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Dictionary)
>   The type Dictionary is used to describe a plain JavaScript object used
>   to pass a set of properties

You can refer the following links for more information on cancelling local notification.

1. [Remove Specific Local Notifications in iOS](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134636/remove-specific-local-notifications-in-ios)
2. [Using Local Notifications in Titanium](http://bencoding.com/2012/06/10/using-local-notifications-in-titanium/)

Comment: I tried the code and now it seems work fine but `Ti.App.iOS.cancelLocalNotification(id)` return `undefined`. It is normal?

Comment: @JMasip: cancelLocalNotification() method returns void. Please refer http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS-method-cancelLocalNotification for more information and Please put the tick mark if my answer resolved your issue